# Error with blogdown::new_site() : "destfile" is missing,

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

I'm trying to create my first website using RMarkdown and blogdown.
But I've got some error I don't understand :

```
> blogdown::new_site(dir = 'Test')
Error in download.file(method = "wget") : 
  argument "destfile" is missing, with no default
> blogdown::hugo_version()
[1] ‘0.24.1’
```

I have looked at the blogdown::new_site function, but there is no mention of destfile and no way to specify it.

I'm running R and RStudio  on Ubuntu 14.04
RStudio Version: 1.0.143
R version: 3.2.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Marie

Comment: try to update R version to the latest and check.

Answer (score 1):

As @OmaymaS pointed out in the comment, if you upgrade to the latest version of R, it should work. But this is a bug anyway for R < 3.4.0, and I have just [fixed it](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/4cdb786b1bc82a5a794cb23218c127182a9075f3). Please make sure you have at least the version 0.0.47 of **blogdown**:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

Comment: Thx for your help. I still have trouble after the update, new error message
  `Error in if (wd1 != wd2) warning("You changed the working directory to ",  : 
  argument is of length zero
    In addition: Warning message:
    In utils::unzip(zipfile) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
    Error in setwd(owd) : cannot change working directory` 
Should I post an issue on github instead of stackoverflow ?

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu 14.04. I tested it on a newer version of Ubuntu but could not reproduce your issue. Anyway, your original issue has been solved. You may open a new post or Github issue with a reproducible example.